# 128 bit MVBITS in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

EDIT :: I reported the [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67140) to the GCC bugzilla. It has now been fixed.

The following example does not compile with gfortran 4.8.4:

```
PROGRAM test
  USE ISO_C_BINDING
  INTEGER(C_INT128_T) :: CINT128T
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I16B  = KIND(CINT128T)
  INTEGER(I16B) :: a, b
  a = 127
  b = 0
  b = IBSET(b,0)
  a = IBCLR(a,0)
  CALL MVBITS(a,0,3,b,0)
END PROGRAM test
```

Here's what I get:

```
$ gfortran test.f90
/tmp/cc2CEkwu.o: In function `MAIN__':
test.f90:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `_gfortran_mvbits_i16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's how gfortran is compiled (i.e., it's the version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
```

I've been doing other bit operations on 128-bit integers (IBSET, IBCLR, BTEST, IBITS) and they all work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Much cleaner would be `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : I16B => c_int128_t` (assuming the compiler has that value).

Comment: Or just `I16B = C_INT128_T`. But it will not change the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime library does not have the 16 byte version of that intrinsic. You are out of luck, get a different compiler, which can do it (I don't know any), or use smaller integers.

You could also write the function yourself in C, if you feel like doing such a thing.

Comment: Do you perhaps know of any FORTRAN libraries that allow bit manipulation of long integers?

Comment: @delete000 I see you reported the bug to the GCC bugzilla. Apart from doing that I have no other direct suggestion.

Comment: You could use the patch offered there to patch your compiler or extract the function from there and link it with your code yourself if you know C. Notice the answer to you there  " Don't know if it actaully works
as your test program has no output and no indication
of the expected result."

Comment: I'm currently compiling GCC with the patch. The problem with this approach is that one depends on the compiler.

Comment: @delete000 You can extract the code for the function `_gfortran_mvbits_i16` and compile it yourself. That way you could use it in all computers with broken gfortran without recompiling it.